# Clickable images in pygame?

Tags: pygame

```
#Imported Pygame
import pygame

#The Colors
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = ( 255, 115, 0)
YELLOW = ( 242, 255, 0)
BROWN = ( 115, 87, 39)
PURPLE = ( 298, 0, 247)
GRAY = ( 168, 168, 168)
PINK = ( 255, 0, 234)
pygame.init()
#The Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,500])
#Name of the window
pygame.display.set_caption("My first game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#The sounds

# Positions of graphics
background_position = [0,0]
singleplayer_position = [350,200]
#The graphics
background_image = pygame.image.load("Castle.png").convert()
singleplayer_image = pygame.image.load("SinglePlayer.png").convert()
singleplayer_image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
#Main Loop __________________________

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    # Copy of background or main menu
    screen.blit(background_image, background_position)

    #Copy of other images
    screen.blit(singleplayer_image, singleplayer_position)
    pygame.display.flip()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and singleplayer_image.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
       print("Hi") 

    clock.tick(60)
#To quit game
pygame.quit()
```

This is basicaly my code, but I keep getting the error that pygame.surface object has no attribute collide point. Im trying to have a clickable image,, but it isn't working to well. If you could show a way that a image can be clickable thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your traceback is explaining the issue perfectly: pygame surfaces do not have an attribute collide_point. Collidepoint belongs to the Rect class, but you are calling it on a Surface object.

To test if if the mouse position collides with the image, you need to have a Rect that describes the images position. So, if you redefine your singleplayer_position...

```
singleplayer_position = Rect(350, 200, 100, 100) # Width/height of 100 pixels.
```

You can now use this variable for Rect methods, such as collidepoint.

```
singleplayer_position.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
```

Note: To have your Rect accurately represent the picture you load..

```
singleplayer_position = singleplayer_image.get_rect()
```

This defaults to the top left, but it has the correct width/height now. Lets move it to where you wanted it.

```
singleplayer_position = singleplayer_position.move(350, 200)
```

Edit, to show how to get mouse position:
Add at the top,

```
from pygame.locals import * # Brings in all the pygame keywords we need.
```

Now, add this to your event for loop.

```
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_pos = event.pos # Now it will have the coordinates of click point.
    if singleplayer_position.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        print('hi')
```

Now, whenever the mousebutton is clicked down, you can check the images Rect (singleplayer_position) to see if it collides with where the mouse was clickd.

Comment: Well i did what you had said, but the Rect doesnt work because it sais it isn't a proper draw command. I did however try drawing a rect around my image which you gave the inspiration/idea for me to do and for the collide point to be with that rect but I dont know how to structure the collide point with that rect and the mouse pos since it sais the mouse pos is an unknown attribute

Comment: You blit using the image and the Rect. The Rect has nothing to do with drawing the image, so you have a different issue there. Also, mouse_pos is an "unknown attribute" because you have never defined it, so Python is trying to say you are using something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I suggest you google your problems and read documentation before you post problems, as your errors could have been solved with a google search

Comment: Ok I had defined the mouse pos and I did the Rect stuff and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it works. Let me know if you have any remaining questions, I'll be happy to answer them